# How to insert element of a 2D Vector into another 2D vector in C++?

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, c++14

I have a 2D Vector `matrix` whose elements I want to shift into another 2D Vector `result` . The only thing is that the positions of the elements are changed in `result` by the logic shown in the code. The program that I have written gets executed but `result` displays all elements as `0` which is incorrect. How to fix this?

**CODE**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    
vector<vector<int>> matrix;
int n;

matrix = {{1,2},{3,4}};
n =  matrix.size();

//Loop to print `matrix` 
cout << "'matrix' 2D Vector" << endl; 

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
    }
    
    cout << "\n";
}

vector<vector<int>> result(n, vector<int> (n));

//Loop to shift elements from `matrix` to `result`     
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
       result[j,n-i+1] = matrix[i][j];
    }
}

//Loop to print `result`
cout << "'result' 2D Vector" << endl;

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        cout << result[i][j] << " ";
    }
    
    cout << "\n";
}

    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
'matrix' 2D Vector
1 2
3 4

'result' 2D Vector
0 0
0 0
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
'matrix' 2D Vector
1 2
3 4

'result' 2D Vector
3 1 
4 2
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Comment: [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) [Why is `using namespace std;` considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0):

First only include `<iostream>` and `<vector>` header files instead of `<bits/stdc++.h>` and your code throws `out_of_range` exception because of the statement `result[j][n-i+1] = matrix[i][j];`, change it `result[j,n-i-1] = matrix[i][j];`